how to raise <asp:CustomValidator> OnServerValidate event on key press only?
After doing many searches I didn't find any reference to raise <asp:CustomValidator> OnServerValidate event on keypress only. For example press 'Enter'.
I found that I must set CausesValidation = false to all my buttons inside the asp.net webforms app, to prevent all these buttons raising OnServerValidate.
Also when I press enter on any textbox that is not related to <asp:CustomValidtor ControlToValidate="Ndit1"
it makes the OnServerValidate event also called!
Here's my code:
<asp:CustomValidator 
  ValidateEmptyText="true" 
  ClientValidationFunction="test" 
  OnServerValidate ="Unnamed_ServerValidate" 
  ControlToValidate="Ndit1" 
  runat="server" 
/>
<dx:ASPxTextBox 
  Caption=" " 
  MaxLength="4" 
  ClientInstanceName="Ndit1" 
  ID="Ndit1" 
  runat="server" 
  CssClass="mb-1" 
  Width="100%" 
  Visible="false" 
  BackColor="Aqua"
>
  <CaptionSettings ShowColon="false" />         
  <CaptionCellStyle Width="140px"></CaptionCellStyle>     
</dx:ASPxTextBox>

And I have other <asp:TextBox> textboxes that also make <asp:CustomValidtor for Ndit1 textbox fire.
So how to solve this problem?

I bet the enter key is a KeyDown event and seems to only be able to be handled client side. This may be relevant. -->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293278/asp-net-enter-key

Dear, I see the article, but that doesn't what I focused. I know I can make __doPostback with keypress client-side on 'Enter' but the actual problem that CustomValidator is always called when I press 'Enter' on any textbox that doesn't belong to Ndit1 textbox. I need only when I press 'Enter' the CustomValidtor server code is executed!. Thanks!

Throwing another url which may help in sorts --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370504/asp-net-validationgroup-validating-correctly-except-on-enter-key
